# How can I name Tuples?

Tags: language-agnostic, string, naming

Is there a language agnostic algorithm to name tuples?

Specifically, I want the following function:

```
  1 => Single
  2 => Double
  3 => Triple
  4 => Quadruple
    ...
 10 => Decuple
    ...
100 => Centuple
```

First of all, is this human-language independent?  For example, will that be understood in Spain and Russia?

Secondly, what is the most efficient way to generate this list?

*Edit*

Just to clarify:

1. This is not for Tuples in the programming sense, but for a tournament system:  Single-elimination, Double-elimination, and etc.
2. I can do translations, I'm just wondering if there was an algorithm that would lend itself well to translations.

Comment: Seems pretty language-dependent to me. Ever seen the French counting system, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want a function for converting from what's used in your system (1, 2, 3, etc) to a nice UI-friendly printable string. If you want it to work for non-English languages then you probably shouldn't have this function at all. Let the Spanish-speaker decide what a nice spanish user-friendly wording is.

If I were writing the function, I'd go to "Quadruple Elimination" only and past that just use "5x Elimination", "6x Elimination" instead. That seems nicer to read to me than some of the awkward sounding later tuple words.

There isn't a nice algorithm you could use for this, as it's not an algorithmic thing.

```
String[4] tupleWords = [ "", "Single", "Double", "Triple", "Quadruple" ];
String getTupleWord(int number) {
    if ( 1 <= number <= 4 ) { 
        return tupleWords[number];
    } else {
        return number+"x";
    }
}
```

is the best you could do.

Answer (score 1):

The only language independent prefixes are going to be the SI ones, and even those aren't really truly language independent.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Si_units

I'm pretty sure that 'tuple' notation is going to require translation for every language you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

What about "Tuple of 10", etc?

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely language-dependent. One trick I like to use in this type of situation is to reword the terminology so it's language-independent. So here I might refactor the UI to read something more like "Number of Elimination Rounds: N" with a number instead of putting a dropdown with "Single", "Double", etc.

Even if you want to do this, I think for your application, if you have to type them all out by hand, it wouldn't be so bad. Are you really ever going to have a centuple-elimination tournament? ;)

Comment: Yes, I will have a centuple elimination tournament.  Though, that specific type will be just for testing purposes.  I am trying to leave this entirely up to whoever is consuming this library.  If they want a Dodecuple-elimination tournament, I want that to be a valid option.

Comment: Then I would advise implementing the API in such a way that the caller must provide a number as opposed to a name (the first suggestion in my answer).